# how to remove a number from a "List<int>"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm programming in Visual studio 2013 C#.

If `listname.add` is adding a number, so how to remove a number from a list?

Comment: btw the list is int list

Comment: what you have done so far

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sounds like you are using a list like a stack. Adding and removing in order(add to end, remove from end). If so, c# has a stack where you can push and pop.

Answer (score 4):

The complement of "add" is not "subtract" for a list, it's "remove".

To remove an item with a specific value you can use the `Remove` method:

```
listname.Remove(value);
```

To remove an item at a specific index you can use the [`RemoveAt` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
listname.RemoveAt(index);
```

To remove multiple values you can use the `RemoveAll` method, which will remove all items that match a condition:

```
listname.RemoveAll(i => i == value);
```

---

Note that the `Remove` method will search through the list until it finds the value. If this is something that you do frequently, you might want to use differnt collection, like a `HashSet<int>` where removing a value is an O(1) operation instead of an O(n) operation.

Comment: @JonathanMoreno: What is it that jumped to 40?

Comment: nvm. I think its ok now.

Answer (score 0):

thanks you all guys. Guffa solved it. you just need to enter "listname.Remove(value);"  its my first question here. and I'm going to come back. for those who wondering- I'm developing A game. I I needed a list to set my levels system, thanks for your help!